# Interference Pattern and dark lines

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, double-slit-experiment, interference

**Two very narrow slits are spaced apart and are
placed 35.0 cm from a screen. What is the distance between the
first and second dark lines of the interference pattern when the slits
are illuminated with coherent light with λ= 550nm**

I'm not asking for an answer for this because I understand the method. I am confused by the theory behind it. When I consulted the solutions manual for this question, they say the first dark line occurs at m = 0 (where m is the order of the image), whereas I thought it occurred at m = 1. Why is this so?

Comment: Can you define $m$ please? There is a point of constructive interference in line with the direction of the incident source, yes.

Comment: And of course one has to define "first" dark line - I presume it is counting up from the center out...

Comment: Different people can mean different things by $m$.   Some people start counting at 0, others at 1 ... in any event, we need to know what it means to you.

Comment: Sorry about that. In this instance "m" is referring to the order of the image. I'll amend my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies everyone, I misunderstood this question greatly. It's talking about the first dark fringe (or the zeroth order dark fringe) which occurs in between 0 and 1. I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

It's not m=0. The sin of d ( or the angle that you will find the dark spots) is equal to ( m+1/2) times the wavelength. m=0,1,2,3.........

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/127928)

Comment: Sure it does. My answer gave the correct formula for the dark spots. The OP thought it occurred at in m=1.  There is more to the formula than that. How else would you have answered it?